# What does "we all got a bit carried away" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm not a native English speaker, but I'm preparing to suffice an IELTS test. I'm practicing my reading skills and I can't give a correct interpretation of: "we all got a bit carried away" in this paragraph:

> Everyone liked this idea and we all got a bit carried away and decided a direct approach would be the best one.

Maybe any of you could help me with this one.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/be-carried-away

Answer (score 1):

To get "carried away" is an idiom meaning to allow your enthusiasm to motivate you to finish a job, to bring a job to completion, or to try something for the first time. Those are just three scenarios of many possible scenarios.

Being "carried away" can be a good thing, but it can also cause problems. In your sentence, the clue that a problem is possible is the presence of the word ***bit***. When people allow their enthusiasm to take over, and at the same time abandon--if only temporarily--common sense or good judgment, they risk going too far. For example, their enthusiasm causes them to make a mistake, cause embarrassment, or even make them regret what they did!

The drinking of alcoholic beverages at a party sometimes decreases the party-goers'  inhibitions, and a group of people who have had too much to drink can do and say some pretty crazy things. In other words, they get "a bit carried away," allowing the alcohol to motivate them to do something they would not ordinarily do if they were completely sober!

So if someone in this group of party-goers says, "OK, guys, let's not get carried away," he or she is encouraging the group not to allow their enthusiasm and their inebriation to cause them to abandon good judgment.

Here's another scenario. Suppose you and a friend are canoeing down a river. You are making good progress and having a good time. Both of you know, however, that not very far ahead in the river, there is a stretch of fast-moving white water, with plenty of jagged rocks to make your passage dangerous, even life threatening.

Even though neither of you has even experienced white water in a canoe before, you both decide to keep going. You are *carried away* in two ways. First, you allow your enthusiasm to cloud your better judgment, and second, the current *literally* carries you away to the dangerous white water up ahead.